# I am getting TypeError Object ABCD has No method compare?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html

**JS Compare Buffers**

I want to compare these two buffer objects:

```
var buffer 1 = new Buffer("ABED");
var buffer 2 = new Buffer("ABED");
var result = buffer 1.compare(buffer 2);

//console.log(result);
if(result < 0) {
    console.log(buffer 1 + " comes before " + buffer 2);
} else if(result === 0){
           console.log(buffer 1 + " is same as " + buffer 2);
       } else {
                console.log(buffer 1 + " comes after " + buffer 2);
              }
```

Comment: Ok, what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

1. You have to change your variables from buffer 1 and buffer 2 to buffer1 and buffer2 because JS do not allow this syntax structure for creating variables. **Space must not be allowed between variable names in JS .**
   Check your console, it gives you Syntax Error : Unexpected Number.
2. Here is the modified code to get Buffers Matched :

   ```
   var buffer1 = new Buffer("ABED");

   var buffer2 = new Buffer("ABED");

   var first = buffer1.toString();

   var second = buffer2.toString();

   if(a === b) {
     console.log("Buffers Matched");
   }
   ```